# Sublime Text 3: phpfmt "autocomplete database not found"

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I am working on PHP files in Sublime Text 3 (Stable channel, build 3103) with the phpfmt plugin.

I have started to see this error message as I type, it was not there yesterday.

```
phpfmt "autocomplete database not found"
```

What is this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the autocomplete database.

Open the command palette by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>.

Select 'phpfmt: build autocomplete database' from the list.

Enter a location for the database file, typically the root directory of your project.